# Looping function and saving to array

Tags: php, arrays, function, random

I'm quite new to php but learning fast, what I'm trying to do is loop a function which generates a random string of characters maybe 10 times and save each random string into an array.

```
function getRandom()
{
    $length = 5;
    $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0,     $length);

    return $randomString;
}
```

Here is my get random string function but now how would I loop it a set number of times and save $randomString into an array each time, any pointers would be great,

Answer (score 0):

Just have to declare an array and save it. For eg:

```
$arr = array(); // declare the array
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $arr[] = getRandom();
}
var_dump($arr); // to check if you are getting the desired result
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$length = 5;

$data = array();

// Set the top value in this case I'm using 10
for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
    $data[$i] = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0,$length);
}

// Print to see new array
print_r($data)
```